# Change the colour (green or red) of the cell depending if stock price is up today

Tags: google-sheets, stock, google-finance, cell-formatting

I am creating a google sheets stock tracker and the problem i have is that i create a command that change the colour of the cell that has the stock price depending if its up or down today.

*For example if Amazon stock is up on Monday to make the cell green, and if its down on Monday to make the cell red.* **I want the cell to become green or red not the numbers inside that cell.**

i use the **=GOOGLEFINANCE('Ticker';"price")** for the custom cell.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This may give you an idea: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115168

Answer (score 0):

#### You can make use of Apps Script's time-based triggers.

So depending on how often you'd like to check the value from the custom cell, you can create a time-based trigger which runs every day at 8AM for instance. Then, after checking the retrieved value from the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function, you can color the cell accordingly.

#### Code

```
function checkValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1');
  var gfval = range.getValue();
  if (gfval < VALUE) 
    range.setBackground('RED');
  else
    range.setBackground('GREEN');
}


function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkValue')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(8)
      .everyDays(1) 
      .create();
}
```

The script above is composed of two functions:

- `checkValue` which is used to check the value returned from the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function and based on it it colors the cell accordingly;
- `createTrigge` which is used to create a time-based trigger which runs everyday at 8AM;

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).